# Pandas groupby->resample deletes columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame containing [key, datetime, receiver, score] attributes.  I want to resample the data by date and receiver in to 5 min. increments.  My approach is below.  First I make 'datetime' in to appropriate 'date' and 'time' types.  Then I groupby 'date' and 'receiver' and use an applied function to do the resampling on each group.

If I remove the 'resample' and just return 'x',  I can see that the data is correctly grouped and passed to the 'process' function (see below).

```
       key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
0   9IIWNCEZD  2017-01-03 08:36:09        A -2.013896e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:09
5   ZEU7GZP47  2017-01-03 08:36:23        A -2.013668e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:23
6   ZEYSUQEI1  2017-01-03 08:36:27        A -2.013640e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:27
10  KW5FYJPIT  2017-01-03 08:36:38        A -2.013632e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:38
17  CE9RZFN5S  2017-01-03 08:36:49        A -2.013631e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:49
21  YQ7KSTNSC  2017-01-03 09:09:32        A -2.029635e+08  2017-01-03  09:09:32
         key             datetime receiver        score        date      time
1  10E1WQXUI  2017-01-03 08:36:11        B -50020185.32  2017-01-03  08:36:11
         key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
2  EHB0FM863  2017-01-03 08:36:12        C -1.008293e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:12
8  KW0UKT04Y  2017-01-03 08:36:35        C -1.007854e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:35
          key             datetime receiver        score        date      time
3   EHFLTCXJX  2017-01-03 08:36:14        D -90002925.25  2017-01-03  08:36:14
12  YD2EHEZUE  2017-01-03 08:36:39        D -90001925.25  2017-01-03  08:36:39
18  KWJ83RTOH  2017-01-03 08:36:50        D -90001725.25  2017-01-03  08:36:50
          key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
4   VHYI21ALA  2017-01-03 08:36:15        E -1.006858e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:15
9   YCXT3OAGJ  2017-01-03 08:36:36        E -1.006308e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:36
11  PUSYD2TBQ  2017-01-03 08:36:38        E -1.006268e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:38
13  3VR53M1VB  2017-01-03 08:36:40        E -1.006264e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:40
16  PV254K83I  2017-01-03 08:36:47        E -1.006258e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:47
19  3W4X8U610  2017-01-03 08:36:53        E -1.005406e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:53
20  DS1EUQNUE  2017-01-03 09:07:34        E -1.005189e+08  2017-01-03  09:07:34
25  T5ZOVXHGW  2017-01-03 10:17:53        E -1.005244e+08  2017-01-03  10:17:53
          key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
7   IRBW5Z94D  2017-01-03 08:36:31        F -1.001900e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:31
14  CE0L7Y8E0  2017-01-03 08:36:40        F -1.001320e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:40
15  YD6ZV5P8A  2017-01-03 08:36:43        F -1.001270e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:43
29  PUXJQTNW2  2017-01-03 10:28:35        F -1.012220e+08  2017-01-03  10:28:35
          key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
24  L0VF2ZUFX  2017-01-04 09:14:37        A -2.026835e+08  2017-01-04  09:14:37
30  OCTPWAQOH  2017-01-04 10:51:29        A -2.025107e+08  2017-01-04  10:51:29
          key             datetime receiver       score        date      time
23  FBJRWFDKB  2017-01-04 09:12:43        B -44649416.6  2017-01-04  09:12:43
          key             datetime receiver        score        date      time
22  JVEE0WOVC  2017-01-04 09:10:32        D -88645751.82  2017-01-04  09:10:32
          key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
28  KWA1CAK36  2017-01-04 10:28:35        E -1.005225e+08  2017-01-04  10:28:35
          key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
26  8IO0DWFDA  2017-01-04 10:22:38        F -1.012222e+08  2017-01-04  10:22:38
27  RK21L5E69  2017-01-04 10:27:46        F -1.012221e+08  2017-01-04  10:27:46
```

BUT if I include the resampling the behaviour is bizarre (see print out at bottom).  It looks like columns are progressively removed until an empty DataFrame is passed to the 'process' function which then errors out.  I understand that 'apply' actually calls a function twice on first row/column but since I don't think I'm mutating any data I don't understand what is happening.  NOTE: I'm not looking for just a solution, I am trying to understand the behaviour as well.

```
s = pd.DataFrame([["9IIWNCEZD","2017-01-03 08:36:09","A",-201389609],["10E1WQXUI","2017-01-03 08:36:11","B",-50020185.32],["EHB0FM863","2017-01-03 08:36:12","C",-100829267.43],["EHFLTCXJX","2017-01-03 08:36:14","D",-90002925.25],["VHYI21ALA","2017-01-03 08:36:15","E",-100685818.41],["ZEU7GZP47","2017-01-03 08:36:23","A",-201366792.15],["ZEYSUQEI1","2017-01-03 08:36:27","A",-201363981.95999998],["IRBW5Z94D","2017-01-03 08:36:31","F",-100190030.42],["KW0UKT04Y","2017-01-03 08:36:35","C",-100785367.43],["YCXT3OAGJ","2017-01-03 08:36:36","E",-100630818.41],["KW5FYJPIT","2017-01-03 08:36:38","A",-201363181.95999998],["PUSYD2TBQ","2017-01-03 08:36:38","E",-100626818.41],["YD2EHEZUE","2017-01-03 08:36:39","D",-90001925.25],["3VR53M1VB","2017-01-03 08:36:40","E",-100626418.41],["CE0L7Y8E0","2017-01-03 08:36:40","F",-100132011.16],["YD6ZV5P8A","2017-01-03 08:36:43","F",-100127011.16],["PV254K83I","2017-01-03 08:36:47","E",-100625778.41],["CE9RZFN5S","2017-01-03 08:36:49","A",-201363081.95999998],["KWJ83RTOH","2017-01-03 08:36:50","D",-90001725.25],["3W4X8U610","2017-01-03 08:36:53","E",-100540645.57],["DS1EUQNUE","2017-01-03 09:07:34","E",-100518856.89999999],["YQ7KSTNSC","2017-01-03 09:09:32","A",-202963512.17000002],["JVEE0WOVC","2017-01-03 09:10:32","D",-88645751.82],["FBJRWFDKB","2017-01-03 09:12:43","B",-44649416.6],["L0VF2ZUFX","2017-01-03 09:14:37","A",-202683512.17000002],["T5ZOVXHGW","2017-01-03 10:17:53","E",-100524437.18999998],["8IO0DWFDA","2017-01-03 10:22:38","F",-101222150.92999999],["RK21L5E69","2017-01-03 10:27:46","F",-101222144.03999999],["KWA1CAK36","2017-01-03 10:28:35","E",-100522494.62],["PUXJQTNW2","2017-01-03 10:28:35","F",-101221964.32],["OCTPWAQOH","2017-01-03 10:51:29","A",-202510655.58]],columns=["key","datetime","receiver","score"])

s["date"] = pd.to_datetime(s["datetime"]).dt.date
s["time"] = pd.to_datetime(s["datetime"]).dt.time

data_YMD = s.copy()
i=0
def process(x):
global i
if i<=6:
 print(x)
y = x.resample("5T", on="time").max()
return y

data15 = data_YMD.groupby(by=["date","receiver"]).apply(lambda x: process(x))
```

Which produces the following output (from the 'print' statement') and error:

```
          key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
0   9IIWNCEZD  2017-01-03 08:36:09        A -2.013896e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:09
5   ZEU7GZP47  2017-01-03 08:36:23        A -2.013668e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:23
6   ZEYSUQEI1  2017-01-03 08:36:27        A -2.013640e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:27
10  KW5FYJPIT  2017-01-03 08:36:38        A -2.013632e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:38
17  CE9RZFN5S  2017-01-03 08:36:49        A -2.013631e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:49
21  YQ7KSTNSC  2017-01-03 09:09:32        A -2.029635e+08  2017-01-03  09:09:32
          key             datetime receiver         score        date      time
0   9IIWNCEZD  2017-01-03 08:36:09        A -2.013896e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:09
5   ZEU7GZP47  2017-01-03 08:36:23        A -2.013668e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:23
6   ZEYSUQEI1  2017-01-03 08:36:27        A -2.013640e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:27
10  KW5FYJPIT  2017-01-03 08:36:38        A -2.013632e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:38
17  CE9RZFN5S  2017-01-03 08:36:49        A -2.013631e+08  2017-01-03  08:36:49
21  YQ7KSTNSC  2017-01-03 09:09:32        A -2.029635e+08  2017-01-03  09:09:32
          key             datetime         score      time
0   9IIWNCEZD  2017-01-03 08:36:09 -2.013896e+08  08:36:09
5   ZEU7GZP47  2017-01-03 08:36:23 -2.013668e+08  08:36:23
6   ZEYSUQEI1  2017-01-03 08:36:27 -2.013640e+08  08:36:27
10  KW5FYJPIT  2017-01-03 08:36:38 -2.013632e+08  08:36:38
17  CE9RZFN5S  2017-01-03 08:36:49 -2.013631e+08  08:36:49
21  YQ7KSTNSC  2017-01-03 09:09:32 -2.029635e+08  09:09:32
          key             datetime         score      time
0   9IIWNCEZD  2017-01-03 08:36:09 -2.013896e+08  08:36:09
5   ZEU7GZP47  2017-01-03 08:36:23 -2.013668e+08  08:36:23
6   ZEYSUQEI1  2017-01-03 08:36:27 -2.013640e+08  08:36:27
10  KW5FYJPIT  2017-01-03 08:36:38 -2.013632e+08  08:36:38
17  CE9RZFN5S  2017-01-03 08:36:49 -2.013631e+08  08:36:49
21  YQ7KSTNSC  2017-01-03 09:09:32 -2.029635e+08  09:09:32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 725, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 742, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 237, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "main.py", line 112, in <lambda>
    data15 = data_YMD.groupby(by=["date","receiver"]).apply(lambda x: process(x))
  File "main.py", line 109, in process
    y = x.resample("5T", on="time").max()
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8449, in resample
    level=level,
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1306, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1443, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 112, in <module>
    data15 = data_YMD.groupby(by=["date","receiver"]).apply(lambda x: process(x))
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 737, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 742, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 237, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "main.py", line 112, in <lambda>
    data15 = data_YMD.groupby(by=["date","receiver"]).apply(lambda x: process(x))
  File "main.py", line 109, in process
    y = x.resample("5T", on="time").max()
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8449, in resample
    level=level,
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1306, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1443, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

FOLLOW-ON NOTES:

1) the problem might have something to do with 'groupby'.  It works if instead of calling "groupby('date','receiver')" I do groupby('date') then call apply a function that does groupby('receiver'), etc. as below.  But this seems very kludgy and I wonder *why* it works?

```
def process(x):
  def scoop(y):
      return y.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(y["datetime"])) \
              .resample("5T").max()
  x = x.groupby("receiver").apply(lambda y: scoop(y))
  return x

data15 = data_YMD.groupby(by=["date"]).apply(lambda x: process(x))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'header' rows.  The columns are properly defined in the pd.DataFrame() call and the 'groups' are properly formed when passed to the 'process' function.

Comment: Sorry, I see the issue. In the future when things wrap (due to wide data) you can instead `print(df.to_string())` which might look messier as plain text, but will render more nicely when posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two separate problems:

1. `resample` requires a datetime column, and your `'date'` is not. This is why you are getting the error `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'` at the end of your traceback. Look at this:

   ```
   s["date"] = pd.to_datetime(s["datetime"]).dt.date
   s["time"] = pd.to_datetime(s["datetime"]).dt.time
   ```

   The `dt.date` and `dt.time` are extracting a string representing date and time. But is a string, not a datetime object. So you cannot `resample` on any of these columns.
2. The combination `groupby().apply()` tries to join together the resulting dataframes made with apply in a multiindex dataframe. However your function used by `apply` is using `resample`, and it seems this makes difficult to rejoin the dataframe. If you fix point 1 only, then you will get a `KeyError` like this: `ValueError: Key 2017-01-03 00:00:00 not in level Index([2017-01-03], dtype='object', name='date')`.

How to fix all this? First, make `"datetime"` a real datetime column, if it isn't yet:

```
s["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(s["datetime"])
```

To solve issue 2, you can use [pandas Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) which provides a useful resampling operation, so no need to use `resample`.

```
data_YMD = s.copy()
data15 = data_YMD.groupby(by=[pd.Grouper(key="receiver"), pd.Grouper(key="datetime", freq="5T")]).max()
```

`data15` output, using your sample data, is:

```
                                    key         score        date
receiver datetime                                                
A        2017-01-03 08:35:00  ZEYSUQEI1 -2.013631e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 09:05:00  YQ7KSTNSC -2.029635e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 09:10:00  L0VF2ZUFX -2.026835e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 10:50:00  OCTPWAQOH -2.025107e+08  2017-01-03
B        2017-01-03 08:35:00  10E1WQXUI -5.002019e+07  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 09:10:00  FBJRWFDKB -4.464942e+07  2017-01-03
C        2017-01-03 08:35:00  KW0UKT04Y -1.007854e+08  2017-01-03
D        2017-01-03 08:35:00  YD2EHEZUE -9.000173e+07  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 09:10:00  JVEE0WOVC -8.864575e+07  2017-01-03
E        2017-01-03 08:35:00  YCXT3OAGJ -1.005406e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 09:05:00  DS1EUQNUE -1.005189e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 10:15:00  T5ZOVXHGW -1.005244e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 10:25:00  KWA1CAK36 -1.005225e+08  2017-01-03
F        2017-01-03 08:35:00  YD6ZV5P8A -1.001270e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 10:20:00  8IO0DWFDA -1.012222e+08  2017-01-03
         2017-01-03 10:25:00  RK21L5E69 -1.012220e+08  2017-01-03
```

Comment: Tnx.  I hadn't paid much attention to pd.Grouper which is much more elegant than my repeated  'apply' approach.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is stating that you are time to resample on a non-datatime dtype column.

Convert s['datetime'] to datetime dtype and resample on s['datetime'] like this:

```
s["date"] = pd.to_datetime(s["datetime"]).dt.date
s["time"] = pd.to_datetime(s["datetime"]).dt.time
s['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(s['datetime'])
data_YMD = s.copy()
i=0
def process(x):
    global i 
    if i<=6:
        print(x)
    y = x.resample("5T", on="datetime").max()
    return y

data15 = data_YMD.groupby(by=["date","receiver"]).apply(lambda x: process(x))
```